# How to find how frequently a specific digit appears in a number?

Tags: real-numbers, decimal-expansion

Supposed I have the number $N$ that is composed from the digits $\underline{d_1d_2d_3...d_i}$, then I define $N^*$ as $d_1+d_2+d_3+...+d_i$, where $d_i$ can take integer values only from $0$ to $9$.  Relation between $d_i$ with $N^*$ and $N$ can be shown by the following equations:

$$N=\sum_{j=1}^i 10^{i-j}d_j$$
$$N^*=\sum_{j=1}^i d_j$$

So for $N=1121221121$, $N^*=1+1+2+1+2+2+1+1+2+1=a_1+2a_2$, where $a_1=6$ and $a_2=4$. The lowercase letter $a$ represents frequency of occurance of its subscript number. In general, as $d_i$ take only $0$ to $9$, one can write $N^*$ as;

$$N^*=a_1+2a_2+3a_3+4a_4+5a_5+6a_6+7a_7+8a_8+9a_9$$

Question: For $N=1121221121$ for instance, where $d_i$ takes $1$ or $2$ only ($N^*=a_1+2a_2$), are there any formula or other expression for $a_1$ and $a_2$ with $N^*=a_1+2a_2$ which can find values of $a_1$ and $a_2$?

$\mathbf{EDIT:}$

$N^*$ is just a solution I introduced to myself to find how many $1$s and $2$s are in $N$. Other solutions to study the digit frequency of $N$ will solve the problem as well. The goal is to find a function $f_1(N)$ that tells how many $1$s are in $N$ for example. And a function $f_{d_i}(N)=a_{d_i}$ that counts how many digit $d_i$ are found in $N$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140500/discussion-on-question-by-a-m-m-elsayed-how-to-find-how-frequently-a-specific-di).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just look at each digit in $n$ and check if it is equal to $d$.

Another way to say this is:

$$
f_d(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor \log_{10} n \right\rfloor} \delta_{d}\left( \left\lfloor 
\frac{n}{10^k} \right\rfloor  \bmod 10\right)
$$

Note that "$\left\lfloor \log_{10} n \right\rfloor +1$" is the number of digits of a number $n$.

Note that "$\left\lfloor 
\frac{n}{10^k} \right\rfloor  \bmod 10$" extracts the $k$th digit, $k=0,\dots,\left\lfloor \log_{10} n \right\rfloor$.

Note that $\delta_d(x)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if } d=x\\0,&\text{if } d\ne x\end{cases}$, also known as [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).